# Leading and trailing spaces must be detected in the names contained in the combobox

Tags: java, swing, combobox, renderer

Im new to Swings, so id like to know something. I have a table, and a Column name-CA1 which has a combobox. Now i want each item in the list of combobox to be according to this condition. Condition is: Leading and trailing spaces must be detected by '#' symbol. So I am trying to use a renderer for the combobox.... but since im new... im not able to figure out.

The Combobox consists of  a list of names... alphanumeric characters along with special characters..

So requirement is that the names, if they consist of spaces before or after it, it must be detected with '#' before or after it respectively.

Comment: Please give an example of input/output you're expecting and what you've tried.

Comment: must you change the # by space? I don't get it...

Comment: for eg, an input list containing names like 1/1ABC, 1/2CBA are comin in. its put into a Vector list= getAllInputNames();

Comment: for all the names  which are in the list,,, which will then get populated into combobox, i need that to be rendered.                             For eg, :1/1ABC , (since there is a space after 1/1ABC) , we need to append 1/1ABC#. if there is space before, then add # before it. so in the combobox i need it to the names to be seen in this format